# Getting state of a country from lat lon for a database in shiny using R

Tags: r, shiny

From the lat and lon in the input csv file, I have to get the state in which the point lies for the entire data, I have tried the revgeocode function for dataframe separately in R, it is working, but when I included it in shiny it is not working and showing the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Can someone help me out with this.....

Code:

```
library(shiny)

#layout of the page

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Hotspot Analysis"),

   sidebarLayout(

     #panel for getting input
      sidebarPanel(
        #for getting input from user
        fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
        #The action button prevents an action firing before we're ready
        actionButton("vis_rep", "Get Visual Representation")
      ),

      #panel for displaying output
      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput('filetable')
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Get the upload file
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath)

  })

  filedata$textaddress <- reactive({
    mapply(FUN = function(lon, lat) revgeocode(c(lon, lat)), filedata$Longitude, filedata$Latitude)})

  filedata$state <- reactive({
    sapply(strsplit(as.character(filedata$textAddress),','),"[",3)})

  observeEvent(input$vis_rep,{
    output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
      filedata()
    })
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. How have you tried [debugging your shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html)?

Comment: debugging shiny app???